# What am I doing wrong with boost::interprocess::message_queue?

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue

I've created a boost::message_queue by the following way:

```
namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;

...

try {
    bipc::message_queue::remove("EDBA90AC-289D-4825-98D9-F85185041676");

    // The below throws exception, no matter what's the name of the queue...

    boost::shared_ptr<bipc::message_queue> mq(new bipc::message_queue(bipc::create_only, "EDBA90AC-289D-4825-98D9-F85185041676", 32767, 256));

    ...
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Now, I cannot get it to work, since the `mq`-creation throws every time the following exception

```
exception: invalid string position
```

This used to work fine with Boost version prior to 1.42, but not anymore. The documentation of Boost's message_queue hasn't changed, so no help from there. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot name an interprocess mechanism with '-' inside. It's written in the documentation:

```
* Starts with a letter, lowercase or uppercase, such as a letter from a to z or from A to Z. Examples: Sharedmemory, sharedmemory, sHaReDmEmOrY...
* Can include letters, underscore, or digits. Examples: shm1, shm2and3, ShM3plus4...
```